# Implement interceptor struts 2 filter all action fields data

Tags: interceptor

I have implemented my first interceptor in struts 2. I think its very basic but when it runs before the action the action fields are all set to null.
Not sure what Im doing wrong
My interceptor class is

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginInterceptor.class);

@Override
public String intercept(final ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    User user = SessionUtilities.getUser(session);

    if (user != null) {
        return invocation.invoke(); 
    }

    Object action = invocation.getAction();
    if (!(action instanceof LoginAction)) { 
        return "loginRedirect";
    }
    return invocation.invoke();
}
```

}

My struts.xml file is

```
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="login" class="ar.com.cipres.framework.logic.LoginInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="login"/>
        </interceptor-stack>        
    </interceptors>

    <default-action-ref name="go.home" />


    <global-results>
        <result name="loginRedirect" type="redirect">go.loginform.action</result>
        <result name="exception" type="redirect">exception.jsp</result>
    </global-results>
```

and finally one of my actions with problems is configured as

```
    <action name="go.asociate.form" method="prepareAsociateData" class="ar.com.cipres.chacabuco.asociate.AsociateAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">chaca/socios/asociateupdate.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Any comment so far?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem
I must include the defaulStack that was omitted when declared the new one.

So I need modify my struts.xml file as

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="login" class="ar.com.cipres.framework.logic.LoginInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="login"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> <!-- Need to be added to mantain default functionality -->         
    </interceptor-stack>        
</interceptors>
```

Going to try later